# command line tdbquery with text index

Tags: sparql, jena, apache-jena, tdb

I trying to run a text search query with Jena via command line.

```
tdbquery  --desc textsearch.ttl  --query search.rq
```

The query return empty results with the messages:

```
17:23:46 WARN  TextQueryPF          :: Failed to find the text index :    tried context and as a text-enabled dataset
17:23:46 WARN  TextQueryPF          :: No text index - no text search performed
```

My assembler file is:

```
    @prefix :        <http://localhost/jena_example/#> .
  @prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
  @prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
  @prefix tdb:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
  @prefix ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .
  @prefix text:    <http://jena.apache.org/text#> .

  ## Example of a TDB dataset and text index
  ## Initialize TDB
  [] ja:loadClass "org.apache.jena.tdb.TDB" .
  tdb:DatasetTDB  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .
  tdb:GraphTDB    rdfs:subClassOf  ja:Model .

  ## Initialize text query
  [] ja:loadClass       "org.apache.jena.query.text.TextQuery" .
  # A TextDataset is a regular dataset with a text index.
  text:TextDataset      rdfs:subClassOf   ja:RDFDataset .
  # Lucene index
  text:TextIndexLucene  rdfs:subClassOf   text:TextIndex .
  # Solr index
  text:TextIndexSolr    rdfs:subClassOf   text:TextIndex .

  ## ---------------------------------------------------------------
  ## This URI must be fixed - it's used to assemble the text dataset.

  :text_dataset rdf:type     text:TextDataset ;
    text:dataset   <#dataset> ;
    text:index     <#indexLucene> ;
    .

  # A TDB datset used for RDF storage
  <#dataset> rdf:type      tdb:DatasetTDB ;
    tdb:location "DB2" ;
    tdb:unionDefaultGraph true ; # Optional
    .

  # Text index description
  <#indexLucene> a text:TextIndexLucene ;
    text:directory <file:Lucene2> ;
    ##text:directory "mem" ;
    text:entityMap <#entMap> ;
    .

  # Mapping in the index
  # URI stored in field "uri"
  # rdfs:label is mapped to field "text"
  <#entMap> a text:EntityMap ;
    text:entityField      "uri" ;
    text:defaultField     "text" ;
    text:map (
         [ text:field "text" ; text:predicate rdfs:label ]
         ) .
```

My query is :

```
  PREFIX text: <http://jena.apache.org/text#>
  PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

  SELECT ?s
  { ?s text:query 'London' ; 
       rdfs:label ?label 
  }
```

I would like to know if I miss any configuration or this query can only be  done inside fuseki.

Comment: Why not asking for help on the Apache Jena mailing list?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can do text search outside Fuseki. The example you took the code from shows how to do this using plain Jena Dataset in Java.

Second, [Andy Seaborne on Jena mailing list](http://users.jena.apache.narkive.com/rUNtoAo5/fuseki-can-t-find-lucene-text-index) suggests the following:

```
SELECT (count(*) AS ?C) { ?x text:query .... }
```

in order to "touch" the index before running the real queries.